# Can Excel save values in a linked list/store values and allow the original place to be deleted?

Tags: excel

Is there a way to be able to input a value in an Excel cell and have it be stored into another cell on another workbook/worksheet?

I am wanting to enter a value in, lets say, A1 and have it be stored in B1 on the second workbook but then when A1 is edited with another value the new value is placed in cell B2 and the next in B3 and so on.

Is this possible?

I used a linked list as an example because I am more familiar with C# and such but not incredible with Excel or it's abilities.

Thank you all for reading.

-Colt

Comment: You will need vba to do that.  formulas are incapable.

Comment: @ScottCraner okay thank you. I appreciate the direct answer. I was simply curious if Excel could perform this native. If you want to make that an answer I will accept it. Thank you